# How Do I Clear $_GET Variables with "href"?

Tags: php, html, get

I have an `a` tag on my search results page (`www.mysite.com/?search=test`). I would like to simply refresh the page and remove all the $_GET variables from the URL by clicking the `<a>` link. Right now I am achieving this with a simple `<a href="?">` but that still leaves the URL with a question mark: `www.mysite.com/?`.

Is it possible to have an `<a>` tag simply clear these variables completely? Or am I stuck with the question mark.

Comment: You can use a [location header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) with `header()` and strip out all other GET-parameters beforehand.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I'll probably end up doing that. I was just hoping there was a way I could do it directly from the ```href```, instead of in ```php```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<a href="{$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']}://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']}">Reset search</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. It really should have been pretty obvious but for some reason I didn't think of it.

Simply set the `href` to the root directory and rebuild back to the page:

```html
<a href="/blog/">Back</a>
```